# css change style of an element on click

Tags: css, onclick, href, visited

I have a list of elements, and i want to change a style of an element when one clicks on the list element(and that specific style to stay the same until the user presses another list item).

I tried using the 'active' style, but no success.

**My code:**

```
#product_types
{       
    background-color: #B0B0B0;
position: relative; /*overflow: hidden;*/
}


#product_types a:active
{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

but the element is 'yellow' only a millisecond, while i actually click on it...

Answer (score 16):

Use the  :focus pseudo class

```
#product_types a:focus
{
 background-color:yellow;
}
```

See this example -> http://jsfiddle.net/7RASJ/

The focus pseudo class works on elements like form fields, links etc.

Comment: See the example link I posted above. Also, what kind of element are you styling?

Comment: @dana: You're using Chrome or Safari, aren't you?

Comment: it is perfect, but doesn't work at all in Chrome... any clue why?

Comment: Probably because it only works on elements that can normally receive focus, like INPUT or A. It won't work on a typical DIV, for example. (I think it's possible to allow any HTML to receive focus, however, by giving it `tabindex="-1"`. Or was it `tabindex="0"`?)

Answer (score 5):

The reason it doesn't work in other browsers is related to the css focus specification. It states:

> The :focus pseudo-class applies while an element has the focus
>   (accepts keyboard events or other forms of text input).

So it seems to work perfectly fine with text input fields or when you focus using the tab key. To make the above compatible with other browsers add the tabindex attribute to each element and this appears to fix the problem.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li id = 'product_types'><a href='#' tabindex="1">First</a></li>
    <li id = 'product_types'><a href='#' tabindex="2">Second</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#product_types  {
    background-color: #B0B0B0;
    position: relative;
}

#product_types a:focus {     
    background-color:yellow;   
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/biped/T9h5h/)